# Second submit button not working in php

Tags: php

I have been having problems with the second button not running like the first button. this is the code I have:

```
        <p>
            <form method="POST">
                <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="password"><br /><br />
                <input value="Login" type="submit" name="log_In">
            </form>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['log_In'])) {
            #$f_name = $_POST['fname'];
            #$s_name = $_POST['sname'];
            #$stud_Id = $_POST['studId'];
            #$uname = $_POST['uname'];
            #$pass = $_POST['pass'];
            #$rpass = $_POST['rpass'];
            #$email = $_POST['email'];
            #$remail = $_POST['remail'];

            #var_dump($f_name);

            header("Location:home.php");

        }
    ?>
</div>
<div align="right">
    <div>
        <p>
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </p>
        <p>
            <form>
                <input placeholder="Forename" type="text" name="fname" id="Forename"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="Surname" type="text" name="sname"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="Student Id" type="text" name="studId"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="uname"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="pass" min="6" max="32"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="Re-type password" type="password" name="rpass" min="6" max="32"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="Email" type="" name="email"><br /><br />
                <input placeholder="Re-type Email" type="remail" name="remail"><br /><br />
                <input value="Sign Up" type="submit" name="sign_Up">
            </form>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['sign_Up'])) {
            header("Location:home.php");
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

"if(isset($_POST['sign_up'])) {" is not being run and is just refreshing the page and removing all items from the form.

thanks

Comment: You cannot use `header()` after any content has been sent to the browser. Do you login and sign-up checks before any HTML is outputted.

Comment: move the isset... header block to top of the page. As said in previous comment

Comment: this hasn't worked, the first isset... worked fine, but the second one didn't, iIknow that this can work a I have done it before, it's been a few months since I've done php so I'm very rusty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `<form>` method is GET. So `if(isset($_POST['sign_Up']))` won't work. Change it to `if(isset($_GET['sign_Up']))`.

Or change your second form tag to:

```
<form method="POST">
```

Remember not to use [header](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php) function after generating HTML content, move it to top!

> **header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

So it will be better if it is like this:

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['log_In']) || isset($_POST['sign_Up'])) {
            header("Location:home.php");
        }
?>
<form method="POST">
    <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="password">
    <br />
    <br />
    <input value="Login" type="submit" name="log_In">
</form>

<div align="right">
    <div>
        <p>
             <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </p>
        <p>
            <form method="post">
                <input placeholder="Forename" type="text" name="fname" id="Forename">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="Surname" type="text" name="sname">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="Student Id" type="text" name="studId">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="uname">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="pass" min="6" max="32">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="Re-type password" type="password" name="rpass" min="6" max="32">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="Email" type="" name="email">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input placeholder="Re-type Email" type="remail" name="remail">
                <br />
                <br />
                <input value="Sign Up" type="submit" name="sign_Up">
            </form>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks dude, I said in my comment on the first bit that I was rusty, clearly I forgot about this, funny think is i remembered to do it on the first form and not the second

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add method="post"

```
<form method="post">
            <input placeholder="Forename" type="text" name="fname" id="Forename"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="Surname" type="text" name="sname"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="Student Id" type="text" name="studId"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="Username" type="text" name="uname"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="password" type="password" name="pass" min="6" max="32"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="Re-type password" type="password" name="rpass" min="6" max="32"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="Email" type="" name="email"><br /><br />
            <input placeholder="Re-type Email" type="remail" name="remail"><br /><br />
            <input value="Sign Up" type="submit" name="sign_Up">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

in second form you have not define the method if method is not defined it will accept the GET method default so change your second form tag by

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```